# How do I make height weight and bmi able to be called in this calculator?

Tags: python, calculator

This is my code in Pycharm and it tells me that my variables are not callable.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2e0d.png

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Off-site links are not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You have done the same syntax error in line 11,12 and 13.
Your code is like : `print("String")(f"{variable}")`
So it is calling the return value of `int("String")` with argument `(f"{variable}")`
The syntactically correct statement would be: `print( f"Height: {height}" )`.
You could also do it without f-strings.

- `print( "Height: ",height )`
- `print( "Height {}".format(height) )`